# how can i fetch the next auto increment value using php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Here i'm trying to get the next auto increment value from database and should be shown on the webpage. Before i'm using mysql and its working perfectly. Now, i'm rewriting my coding using pdo but i'm stuck in that place. Below i've posted my codes. How can i fetch the next auto increment value using PHP PDO?

**Using Mysql** :

```
include('config.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'ebvouchers'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $autoid = array(
    'next_increment' => htmlentities( $data['Auto_increment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' )
    );
    echo $autoid['next_increment'];
```

**Using PDO** :

```
    <?php
        include('config.php');
        $stmt = $db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ebvouchers");
        $size = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        HERE ??? I"M STUCK
    ?>
```

Comment: have you done a var_dump or print_r of $size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
   include('config.php');
    $string = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'ebvouchers'";
    $query = $db->connection->prepare($string);
    $query->execute();
    $size = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $size['Auto_increment'];
```

Comment: but i'm getting this following fatal error Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1065 Query was empty

Comment: Did you try to replicate the code I've supplied in your own code?

Comment: Great! Don't worry, programming is a learning experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

With PDO, I use this *"single line"* solution :

```
$nextId = $db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['Auto_increment'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

and in php:

```
echo $size['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
```